# .Net MediaPlayer works in unit test, but not within IIS WebSite

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, vs-unit-testing-framework

I need to grab a screen shot from a video file, and determine the length, size (height x width) of the video, and verify if the video file seems legit.

Therefor I wrote a Class Library with as input a Video File, and it will return all relevant information.

The Unit Test is working fine, with every video file I provide. All properties of NaturalVideoHeight, NaturalVideoWidth, NaturalDuration are set (to a correct value).

When I run this code in IIS (MVC Project), even if I wait for 10 seconds (see while loop), only the NaturalDuration is set (and to a correct value). The other properties NaturalVideoHeight, NaturalVideoWidth are 0.

Does anyone know why this behavior does occur? And how I can work around it.

```
        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

        mediaPlayer.ScrubbingEnabled = true;
        mediaPlayer.Volume = 0;
        mediaPlayer.Open(new Uri(videoFrom));
        mediaPlayer.Position = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
        mediaPlayer.Pause();

        int i = 0;

        while (mediaPlayer.NaturalVideoHeight == 0 && i < 1000)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(10);
            i++;
        }
```

Comment: Not working has many meanings, Is your code throws any error or returning invalid results?

Comment: Could it be caused  by the fact that IIS is running on an service account that doesn't have *interact with desktop* enabled which causes the mediaplayer to fail for certain functions, like width and height calculations?

Comment: @Thangadurai Reformulated the not working part...

Comment: Is your website running under a username that has network access? Is it even allowed to download the url?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen
The file is loaded from a local disk. If I provide an invalid path (filename), an exception is thrown.

Otherwise I would not have expected the NaturalDuration is set to correct file.

Comment: @rene If I need to guess in the dark, yes, that would be the answer. I don't understand why the file is partially loaded.